# Install firefox on elastic beanstalk using ebextensions config?

Tags: firefox, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, xvfb

I need to install firefox on my elastic beanstalk deployment. How can I use the ebextions config to install firefox?

I have to run headless firefox with Xvfb for generating screenshots from a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package created by [lambda-linux](https://lambda-linux.io/blog/2015/01/28/announcing-firefox-browser-support-for-amazon-linux/). The setup will look like this:

.ebextensions/firefox.config:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/setup_firefox.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        curl -X GET -o RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll https://lambda-linux.io/RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll
        sudo rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll
        curl -X GET -o epll-release-2015.09-1.1.ll1.noarch.rpm https://lambda-linux.io/epll-release-2015.09-1.1.ll1.noarch.rpm
        sudo yum -y install epll-release-2015.09-1.1.ll1.noarch.rpm
        sudo yum --enablerepo=epll install firefox-compat

commands:
    set_firefox:
        test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
        command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/setup_firefox.sh
```

.ebextensions/99_finalize_setup.config:

```
commands:
  99_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
    command: touch /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
```

Comment: I tried these commands manually through SSH, but when trying to install  **epll-release-2015.09-1.1.ll1.noarch.rpm**, it says that it needs amazon linux version 2015.09 whereas the amazon linux deployed on beanstalk is version 2015.03

Comment: any reason not to upgrade to the latest?

Comment: Upgrading... I'll test it out and see if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this install Firefox or just enables firefox compatibility?

Comment: Is Firefox installed after running this? If so, where can I find the binary path?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as above but with updated files I got from here: https://lambda-linux.io/

```
files:
      "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/setup_firefox.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            curl -X GET -o RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll https://lambda-linux.io/RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll
            sudo rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-lambda-epll
            curl -X GET -o epll-release-2017.03-1.2.ll1.noarch.rpm https://lambda-linux.io/epll-release-2017.03-1.2.ll1.noarch.rpm        
            sudo yum -y install epll-release-2017.03-1.2.ll1.noarch.rpm        
            sudo yum --enablerepo=epll install firefox-compat

commands:
    set_firefox:
        test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
        command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/setup_firefox.sh
```